# Exception - file is already being used by another program

Tags: c#, file, text, io

I am currently working on a project for editing text documents with a C# console application. When I start the program, it asks the user to choose between editing an existing text document or creating a new one. If I create a new one, edit it or whatever, when I try to save it with "File.WriteAllLines(path, list.ToArray)", I receive a exception saying that I can't access that file because it is being used by another program. I had tried some things but none seemed to work, so here's my code:

```
    bool loop = false;
    string path = "";

    do
    {
        loop = false;

        Console.WriteLine("If you want to create a new text document type 1, or if you want to edit");
        Console.Write("an existing document type 2: ");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (choice == "1")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the path, where you want your text document to be created: ");
            path = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter a name for your text document: ");
            path = (path + Console.ReadLine() + ".txt");

            File.Create(path);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else if (choice == "2")
        {
            Console.Write("Text document path: ");
            path = Console.ReadLine();        
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            loop = true;
            Console.WriteLine();
            MessageBox.Show("You can only type 1 or 2. Type '1' for creating a new text document and '2' for editting and existing document.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }



        if (loop == false)
        {
            bool repeat = true;

            do
            {
                string[] lines;

                try
                {
                    lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    lines = new string[1] { "EMPTY" };
                }

                List<string> LineList = new List<string>();
                int i = 1;

                foreach (var eachLine in lines)
                {
                    LineList.Add(eachLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i, eachLine);
                    i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("Line to edit: ");
                int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                n--;

                Console.Write("{0}. ", n + 1);
                try
                {
                    LineList[n] = LineList[n].Replace(LineList[n], Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    LineList.Insert(n, Console.ReadLine());
                }

                File.WriteAllLines(path, LineList.ToArray());  // Cannot access the file because it is being used by another program exception


                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue editting the document? Y/N");
                string LoopEnd = Console.ReadLine();
                if (LoopEnd == "n" || LoopEnd == "N" || LoopEnd == "no" || LoopEnd == "NO" || LoopEnd == "No")
                {
                    repeat = false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            } while (repeat);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();


    } while (loop);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The file is open? (notepad or something..)

Comment: When do you plan to close the file created by `File.Create(path);` ? See what it returns...

Comment: its a .txt file. What do you mean by closing the file? File.Create just creates the file doesnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have opened the file and didn't close it.

You should use the stream from the File.Create and then close it.

But I recommend to use StreamWriter.

```
FileStream newFile = File.Create(path);
newFile.Close();

// ...

File.WriteAllLines(LineList.ToArray());
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks for the help. I am kind of new to C#, that's the first time that I hear about that 'Stream' thing.

Answer (score 3):

When *creating* a file, you're actually *opening* it, just like you will do when opening a regular file on your computer.

Use `using` to dispose and close it automatically:

```
using (File.Create(path))
{
    ///.....
}
```

Comment: @aj.toulan Thanks! It is really a good practice for many reasons.